# Changing progress bar width, without moving elements inside

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm lacking ideas as of how to change the display width of a progress bar without moving the elements that are inside.

I'd like to achieve the following:

[image]

My current code for one player entry is:

```html
<div class="row playerInfo">
  <div class="row healthProgress progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" style="width: 100%; height: 25px;">
    <img id="primaryWeapon" class="col-4 pull-left no-padding img-responsive" src="/images/weapons/weapon_ak47.png" height="25px" />
    <p class="playerName col-6 text-right no-padding">Matias49</p>
    <p class="playerHealth col-1>100</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I guess, instead of using a `progress-bar` bootstrap class, I should go for an empty `div` and play around with `width` and the `background-color` that I stack under the player informations: the weapon, the name and health count, but I have no idea how to achieve this in css.
Or is there some kind of way I could make it work using the bootstrap `progress-bar` class?

nb: I know I probably should have wrapped the `progress-bar` div in a `progress` one.

Comment: Can you add a style to your code? Maybe a web icon as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much @Pablo Darde for commenting but I managed to deal with it by stacking one div onto another as I was thinking at first.

In the end my code looks like this:

```
<div class="row playerInfo">
    <div class="row healthProgress progress-bar role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" style="width: 100%; height: 25px></div>
    <div class="row firstRow style="position: absolute;">
        <img id="primaryWeapon" class="col-4 pull-left no-padding img-responsive" src="/images/weapons/weapon_ak47.png" height="25px" />
        <p class="playerName col-6 text-right no-padding">Matias49</p>
        <p class="playerHealth col-1>100</p>
    </div>
</div>
```